# How to downgrade an Angular Project?

Tags: angular, angular7

Is it possible to downgrade an Angular project?

I made the project using Angular 7, but I need it to be in Angular 5.

I'm not talking about the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You need to thoroughly check which functionality angular had made obsolete and then you have to made changes in your code accordingly. Unfortunately there is no command for it :).

Comment: Hmm. @masu9 follow this official link https://angular.io/guide/change-log, This log calls attention to recent significant changes.